# find max element k placement in array (with logk complexity)

Tags: c, arrays, complexity-theory

i am trying to write a c program to find max element 'k' placement in an array. the array is with unknown integers and the order inside it is like a pyramid. example: `a = { -1, 4, 9, **17**, 8, 3 }` also can look like this: `a = { **11**, 9, 4, -9 }` (ascending then descending or only descending or only ascending). this is my code below with O(logn) complexity, how can i do it with O(logk) complexity? thanks.

```
int find_k_logn(int *arr, int n) //(Ex1) --> log2n function, find k placement
{
    int low = 0, high = n - 1, mid;

    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (high + low) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1] && arr[mid] > arr[mid - 1])
            return mid;
        else if (arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1] && arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1])
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search). Note that in practice an exponential search is going to be slower than a simple binary search, unless `n` is much larger than `k`.

Comment: @user3386109 Seems you can make an answer.

Comment: Tiran, when `while (low <= high)` is false, `int find_k_logn()` lacks a `return`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it shouldn't be false, as there should always be an element that is bigger than the rest. for this specific problem we are suppose to assume the input is correct. thanks for the heads up tho.